# Intellitrace isn't capturing the arguments and return values

Tags: intellitrace

The value is displayed as {unknown} but according to the documentation it should display it

[image]

Thanks for helping me out. I've been looking for this quit some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was cause by and extension...

Answer (score 0):

You will see the {unknown} value when the data was not collected for the parameter values.  By default certain modules/assemblies do not have the data collected to keep performance impact to a minimum.

Module exclusion/inclusion is determined by the setting in Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace -> Modules.  If you have not altered these settings then the default will *exclude* any modules that have been signed using a Microsoft key or that have the string "Microsoft." anywhere in the assembly name (e.g. TestingIntelliTraceFromMicrosoft.dll).

If you have changed the settings then make sure that your assembly is not excluded if you are using the exlusion list setting (i.e. Collect data from all modules except for the following:) or if you are using the inclusion list (i.e Collect data from only the following modules:) make sure that the name of your assembly will match one of the string entries in the list.